# How do you make numbered equations in latex?

Tags: formatting, equations, amsmath

I would like to put in a code that automatically assigns a number to the equations in my documents preferably aligned on the right hand side.

How can I go about this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

$$\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} = \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}= 0$$. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: has this question really not been asked before?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use  display math environment such as `equation`:

[image]

## Notes:

- The `d` in `dt` should be upright as `d` is an operator, not a variable. Have defined a macro for that and corrected it below.

### References:

- You should not use a the TeX way of using a `$$` to enter display math. See
  [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)
- An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode?lang=en).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} = \frac{\dd{}{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{\dd{t}^2} = 0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think we don't need the trailing `s` in `Voss's`.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: Have corrected that.

Comment: “See Why is `\[...\]` prefereable to `$$`”; yeah, especially Harrold's and Hendrik's comments to the accepted answer.

Comment: @morbusg: Thanks for pointing those comments out.  Perhaps those should be added as an answer so that thy are not missed.  But, then David Carlisle's answer about `$$` not easily being re-definable might be a better reason.

Comment: @kissmyarmpit nothing wrong with a trailing s there.  perfectly acceptable according to conventional grammar.

Answer (score 22):

You can also use the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
%Equations with numbering
\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\\
                              &= 0
\end{align} 

%Equations with no numbering in specific line by using \nonumber
\begin{align}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\nonumber\\
                              &= 0
\end{align}

%Equations without numbering
\begin{align*}
\ddot{\underline{\mathbf{r}}} &= \frac{d{^2}\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt^2}\\
                              &= 0
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not working for me.EDIT sorry I didn't notice those \\ after the equation.

Comment: @Magpie Is everything working fine now?

Comment: Yes, I was just having a sloppy moment. Thanks for your help. I selected the other answer because it does what I want more precisely but I appreciate your solution too.

Comment: How can I reference those lines then?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa label with the command `\label{    }` then reference with `\ref{ }`