# Number only some equations in an equation array

Tags: equations, numbering

I have an equation array consisting of around 9 equations, however I wish to number only some of them. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `\nonumber` before the \\.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75768/10898

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\notag` and/or `\nonumber` from `amsmath` (or improvised `mathtools` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  x &= y \\\nonumber
  x &= 3 \\
  y &= 10 \\ \notag
 \therefore\ x &\neq y \\
   x &= y \\\nonumber
  x &= 3 \\
  y &= 10 \\ \notag
 \therefore\ x &\neq y \\
 ? &=?
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]